# Call a function inside an object in AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('snswMock').factory('snswService', ['$http','$location' ,
    function ($http, $location ) {

        'use strict';

        return {

            getData: function(jsonData){

                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                var serviceUrl = getServiceUrl();
                $http({
                        url: serviceUrl,
                        dataType: 'string',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: jsonString
                    }).success(function(response){
                        alert ("Success");
                    }).error(function(error){
                        alert ("Save company!");
                    });

      },

        getServiceUrl :function(){

                    var host = $location.host();
                    if (host === 'localhost') {
                        return $location.protocol() + '://' + host + ':9000/services/insert';
                    } else {
                        return $location.protocol() + '://' + host + '/services/insert';
                    }

            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Hi am very new to the angular
this is my service

I am calling `getServiceUrl` inside `getData` function i am getting the below error

`angular.js:11706 ReferenceError: getServiceUrl is not defined`

can anyone please help me how can I call the method. is there any other way is there to call web service by passing a string as post request?

Comment: try calling snswService.getServiceUrl() after injecting this service

Comment: Any feedback @bhargava?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` context to access a global object function -> `this.getServiceUrl()`. In your case `myFactory` is the object and inside your object all functions are globally accessible inside your object scope by using `this` context.

```
angular.module('snswMock').factory('snswService', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {

  'use strict';

  var myFactory = {

    getData: function(jsonData) {

      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      var serviceUrl = this.getServiceUrl(); //modified

      $http({
        url: serviceUrl,
        dataType: 'string',
        method: 'POST',
        data: jsonString
      }).success(function(response) {
        alert("Success");
      }).error(function(error) {
        alert("Save company!");
      });

    },

    getServiceUrl: function() {

      var host = $location.host();
      if (host === 'localhost') {
        return $location.protocol() + '://' + host + ':9000/services/insert';
      } else {
        return $location.protocol() + '://' + host + '/services/insert';
      }

    }
  }

  return myFactory;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller where you are trying to access this service, do below things.

1. Inject this service in the controller.
2. Call this service like below

   ```
   snswService.getServiceUrl();
   ```

Comment: This doesnt make any sense. This is currently possible by using the users code. He also doesn't call the `getServiceUrl()` on a factory instance. He tries to call `getServiceUrl()` inside the factory object.